# Implementing TFS Pull Requests

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Now that TFS 2013 supports git natively, how does one go about implementing a pull request policy / workflow - that is, mandating pull requests and code reviews to get code merged in?

Comment: Pull request is now available. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/06/10/visual-studio-online-update-june-10.aspx

Comment: @RosdiKasim - As I understand it is available only for Visual Studio Online, which we are not allowed to use. I was asking about the on-premises regular TFS 2013.

Comment: Pull requests are available on-premises starting with TFS 2013 Update 4

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### As of Oct 2014:

Pull requests are now supported in both [TFS 2013 update 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/09/03/vs-amp-tfs-2013-update-4-ctp-1-is-available.aspx) and in Visual Studio Online. Combined with removing the Push permission to certain branches, this effectively allows you to setup a policy.

For more advanced policy like features, you can use the ISubscriber interface to build a 'commit hook' until Microsoft fully implements such features. [Read more here](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/).

[More information on Pull Requests can be found in this blog post from the Visual Studio team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/06/10/visual-studio-online-update-june-10.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the info! I hope MS does a decent job so we can adopt good workflows

Comment: Contribute your feature requests on UserVoice so that your thoughts are recorded :).

Comment: I did, hope that gets their attention - almost 300 votes

Comment: On 3 Apr 2014 when asked about pull requests Brian Harry says "Actually we start dogfooding them this sprint :)  There's still a lot of polish and fit & finish work to do but it's coming along well and I think we'll be making it available before too long." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/02/tfs-2013-2-update-2-released.aspx#10513654

Comment: Pull request has been added to Visual Studio Online. It is now time to update this answer. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/06/10/visual-studio-online-update-june-10.aspx

Comment: Which licenses do pull requests require? Premium and above just like Code Reviews in TFVC?

Comment: Pull requests are a standard feature at the moment. A CAL suffices.

Comment: Is this available when using TFS for source control as opposed to git?

Comment: @MikeDevenney That's worth a question on it's own. You can get similar behavior using buddy builds, shelving  and the code review workflow, but it's not the same thing. A real on-par feature currently does not yet exist in TFVC.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks Jesse, I just put it out there.

Comment: What could cause a grayed out "Create Pull Request" in the context menu within Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @mryoung have you published your topic branch yet?